# Ignoring System#exit() from reflective call

Tags: java, reflection

I have the following question. Suppose that one has `ClassA` with a bog standard main class. `ClassA` performs a reflective invocation to `ClassB#main()`. `ClassB`'s main method does a system exit at some point which in turn will also terminate the execution of `ClassA#main()`.

Now my question is the following, is there a way to ignore the `System#exit()` from `ClassB`'s main thus not killing the JVM and resuming running the main method of `ClassA`. Could something like that happen without a lot of tampering on `ClassB`?

Consider the following very simple example as a use case:

```
public class ClassA  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ClassB.class.getMethod("main", String[].class)
            .invoke(null, (Object) null);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

}

public class ClassB {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("I am running!");
        System.exit(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a `SecurityManager` that has a `checkExit` method that throws a `SecurityException`?

Comment: This feels like an XY problem - what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth. My point is to have a single small Swing app that acts a an entry point for various other Swing apps, thus I would like for the user to be able to launch on from that place but not kill the entrypoint once the other app finishes.

Comment: You could run them as separate processes with `ProcessBuilder`. Using `SecurityManager` is a bit hacky considering you're in control of the programs.

Comment: @Kayaman can you provide some source for doing so?

Comment: Your Google works just as well as mine.

Comment: @Kayaman fair enough